# Error while creating pdf file in php

Tags: php, string, pdf-generation

i used this code to create pdf from posted data :

```
header('Content-Type: application/pdf' );
header('Content-Disposition: filename=cert.pdf');


$date = date('F d,Y');
// open our template file
$filename ='PHPCertification.pdf';
$output = file_get_contents($filename);
// replace the place holders in the template with our data
$output = pdf_replace('<<NAME>>',strtoupper($name),$output);
$output = pdf_replace('<<Name>>',$name,$output);
$output = pdf_replace('<<score>>',$score,$output);
$output = pdf_replace('<<mm/dd/yyyy>>',$date,$output);
// send the generated document to the browser
echo $output;
```

but when i run this code i occur this error :
     Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_STRING) in C:\xampp\htdocs\ah\pdf.php on line 40

PHPCertification.pdf is existed.

but line 40 is : header('Content-Type: application/pdf' );

i can not find an error here

Comment: As the error message says, there's a syntax error on line 40. You'll need to point us to that line (or look what's wrong in it)

Comment: header('Content-Type: application/pdf' );
this is line 40 . i can not find error here

Comment: It's not your PHPCertification.pdf file, but pdf.php file. Read the error carefully.

Comment: i dont talk about PHPCertification.pdf file.
error is in pdf.php on line 40 . and line 40 is header('Content-Type: application/pdf' ); on pdf.php